# Laravel routing using 2 models and 2 controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

So I'm using Laravel 5.8, and I have a resource and version model

both have controllers (ResourcesController --resource and VersionController --resource) and I need to do stuff like example.com/resources/{id}/versions/ to access versions.

How can I do this? (BTW I'm still new to this, I started elarning Laravel 4 days ago and did a full blogging site, now I'm trying to expand my knowledge).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define [nested resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources) like:

```
Route::resource('resources.versions', 'VersionController');
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much, will mark this as resolved once it lets me do so.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

In your routes:

```php
Route::get('resources/{resource}/versions', 'ResourcesController@getVersions');
```

In your `ResourcesController`:

```php
use App\Resource;

public function getVersions(Resource $resource)
{
    return $resource->versions;
}
```